# How to create a float window floating above all other windows just like twitter?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow, nspanel

The twitter app has a float window when you click the contextual menu "Tweet",is it a NSPanel?
How to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at NSWindow's **setLevel:** method:

> Each level in the list groups windows
>   within it in front of those in all
>   preceding groups. Floating windows,
>   for example, appear in front of all
>   normal-level windows. When a window
>   enters a new level, it’s ordered in
>   front of all its peers in that level.

-- from NSWindow's [setLevel:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCICJDAF) reference.

You may also find [Matt Gemmell's MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass) project helpful:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with an NSWindow subclass. Check Matt Gemmell's custom `MAAttachedWindow` class [here](http://mattgemmell.com/source).